# What characters are allowed in a file?

Tags: file, ascii, special-characters

I am using a PHP script to write compressed data to a txt file. The data could include any of the 255 ASCII characters. On [asciitable.com](http://asciitable.com), there is a character for file seperator (28). I want to know if it will cause trouble if a file seperator, or any special character, is written to a file.

EDIT: Tested on Wampserver on windows, and adding a file separator to a file works fine.

Comment: There are 128 ASCII characters (including NUL), not 255. Do you mean you're writing arbitrary binary data to a file with the extension `.txt`? That would be lying.

Comment: Asciitable.com says that characters 128-255 are extended ascii codes.

Comment: well, then that website is wrong. ASCII does not define anything called "extended ASCII". The interpretation of values 128-255 (which makes a total of 256, not 255) is totally independent of ASCII and many different and incompatible interpretations exist. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: I checked wikipedia, and I think you're right. Ascii is only defined to be 128 characeters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it should cause a problem. But since you're outputting binary data which isn't meant to be human-readable, there's no need to use a text file (and it's even arguably misleading).

Were you hoping to read the compressed data in a text editor for debugging purposes? Because if you are, you should be wary of the fact that different text editors handle non-printable control characters in different ways. My version of Notepad displays nothing for a file-separator character while Notepad++ displays an FS symbol. And based on my experiences in viewing data output from a machine, there's even variance between different versions of Notepad. You should really use a hex editor to view it.

Comment: I just thought that maybe the server's filesystem uses the file separator character to separate files on the hard drive.

Comment: Nah, FS isn't used for that purpose. In fact, I've never seen an app which uses that character. I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: I think FS is a remnant of 1960's operating systems. I'd never even heard of it until now.

Comment: ASCII is an ancient (1960s, IIRC) and defunct character set.  FS was useful for batch processing systems and block-mode terminals back then, but has no standard meaning in modern systems.